# how to stream input/mic audio in Node Js without SOX or Navigator.getUserMedia()

Tags: node.js, electron, audio-streaming, node-streams, google-translation-api

I am developing a windows/mac app with help of NodeJs electron and google-translation-API where I need to to get the audio stream from the mic,

currently, I am using a package `node-record-lpcm16` which working perfectly but This module requires you to install `SoX`,

in the end, I want my windows/mac app does not require every user to install sox in their system,

I have googled a lot but could not find any good npm package which not required SOX,

can you please help me how I can get the same result(getting the audio stream from mic) 
without depending on SOX